# Deploy data and code to production server from dev server Magento 2

Tags: deployment, version-control, magento2

I read lots of articles here, but I get more confused.
Can anyone help a newbie with more details?

My scope:
1 - I have a local server with magento 2.4.4 open source
2 - I have a cloud server with production store running, magento 2.4.4 as well.

NOTE: I'm using gitlab for code management. Code deployment is simple for me and it's working fine.

My problems: every week I make a lot of changes at the dev base and push it into production. **My problem is with the data**. Example, I installed a new module, configured it and tested it on stage. When deploying it, I need to replicate all settings in the production server admin manually.
Another issue is server downtime when I made this kind of change.

**My questions:
What is the best way to work with the magento2 deployment, for updating files and data simultaneously from stage to production?
What is the best practice to avoid server downtime when performing this deployment?**

Thank you very much

Comment: You seem to need a continuous integration / continuous deployment (CI/CD) pipeline. Minimising the downtime of the question is off-topic, that belongs to serverfault as that's more of an infrastructure question, not a programming one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm looking for pipeline to study it. About the "down time" I means talked about deploy and compilament of magento commands or manually admin configurations(store at maintenance mode)

Comment: There are lots of different ways to set up a pipeline. A lot depends on how your infrastructure is set up, what os you use, etc. Product recommendations are off topic here on SO, so you need to do your own research and choose the products you need. Configuration of production servers and applications definitrly belong to serverfault, no SO. Devops (CI/CD pipeline) is a grey area, some questions will be accepted here on SO, others will be pushed to serverfault.